# Trouble escaping my own string, date variable in file name

Tags: string, powershell

Im having a bit of a bump in trying to grasp quotes, single and double within powershell.

I have a file that is auto generated each day, named filecsv20140306.csv, where 20140306 is the date.  I want to run a script that takes this file each day, and processes it.

I can do the following..

```
$filename = 'filecsv' + (get-date -uformat %Y%m%d) + '.csv'
$file = import-csv \\fs-01\daily\$filename
```

Then when I read that file, it is as it should be.

How would I get this into one line? I tried..

```
$file = import-csv \\fs-01\daily\filecsv + (get-date -uformat %Y%m%d) + csv ..
```

whether I put single quotes, no quotes i seem to get an error stating cannot bind parameter, cannot convert valie "20140306" to type "System.Char"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always just use a `;` instead of a new line like such:

```
$filename = 'filecsv' + (get-date -uformat %Y%m%d) + '.csv';$file = import-csv \\fs-01\daily\$filename
```

But I think what you wantis going to be:

```
$file = import-csv "\\fs-01\daily\filecsv$(get-date -uformat %Y%m%d).csv"
```

When in the double quotes anything in a `$(<code>)` enclosure will be processed before returned as a part of the string, so as far as Import-CSV is concerned this:

```
"\\fs-01\daily\filecsv$(get-date -uformat %Y%m%d).csv"
```

looks like this:

```
"\\fs-01\daily\filecsv20140306.csv"
```